# Trying to call json ID in MVC controller but I am getting this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get ID from a json file in an ASP.NET MVC controller but for some reason it gives me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.
JsonFile:

```
"Id": "1",
"FirstName": "FirstName",
"LastName": "LastName",
"Age": "21",
```

C# class:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

ASP.NET MVC controller:

```
model = UserRepository.GetUserById(User.Id);   // error line
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @haldo I understand why the error is coming from your attached link but I can't find a solution for it.

Comment: How are you initializing `User`?

Comment: You should change `Id` and `Age` in your json data to numbers as they are `string`s as of now.

Comment: like this " public Models.User user { get;  }"

Comment: Ok. Let me try that

Comment: Can you share the code which converts json to the user objects?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I think I haven’t convert the json to user object but I do have a class which I have shown in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should change `Id` and `Age` to numbers, otherwise the model binder will give you an exception. Something like this:

> The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.Id | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 11
> `

Your JSON should now look like this:

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "FirstName": "FirstName",
    "LastName": "LastName",
    "Age": 21
}
```

Then you should add a parameter `User user` to your action instead of declaring the `user` variable as property of the controller like you probably did as you said in one of your comments.

You should end up with something along these lines:

```
[HttpPost]
public string MyAction(User user)
{
    if (user is null)
        return "Bad request :(";

    // Do things with user.

    return $"Id: {user.Id}, First Name: {user.FirstName}, Last Name: {user.LastName}, Age: {user.Age}";
}
```